# problem with "Run the sample app: HoloLens - Visual Studio (C++/WinRT)" tutorial and HoloLens

Tags: azure, visual-studio, augmented-reality, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

in the tutorial "Run the sample app: HoloLens - Visual Studio (C++/WinRT)"
I am having problems with the "Configure account identifier and key" step it asks for three inputs SpatialAnchorsAccountKey, SpatialAnchorsAccountId, and SpatialAnchorsAccountDomain. the code accompanying this tutorial asks for AnchorExchangeURL as well.
the tutorial doesn't mention this, but it can't be left blank, so I am unable to continue with the tutorial.
does anyone know the solution?

webpage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-hololens?tabs=azure-portal

I tried following the instructions in the tutorial.
I expected to be able to export to HoloLens.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/blob/08e00c61d419e2e322be883f9adf3ee8bf0eb0ed/HoloLens/DirectX/SampleHoloLens/ViewController.cpp#L49) line,
above text says: // Set this to the url for the service created in the 'SharingService' sample.

This URL can be left empty if you are not using a Sharing spatial anchor webservice and you want to query Azure Spatial Anchors service for any operation. You can find more about sharing anchors between devices in this doc [Tutorial: Share spatial anchors across sessions and devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-share-anchors-across-devices?tabs=azure-portal%2CVS%2CUnityHoloLens).

Comment: How do you find the URL if you do want to use spatial anchor webservices.

Comment: if you host your own sharing service API, you need to provide that URL in the app. our documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-share-anchors-across-devices?tabs=azure-portal%2CVS%2CUnityHoloLens#deploy-the-sharing-anchors-service gives you steps on how to deploy to Azure and get the URL from Azure portal